# using highslide js in web2py application?

Tags: web2py, highslide

I am trying to view my image gallery by using highslide js in my application.

But I am not able to load/link graphics folder to `hs.graphicsDir`. As this is necessary for all the effects in viewing my image gallery.

I am struck here. Could anyone please help me to fix this?

Comment: You just need to set this, for example: http://highslide.com/ref/hs.graphicsDir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the highslide documentation, it looks like you could put the highslide files in /web2py/applications/yourapp/static/js/highslide/, and then in layout.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{=URL('static', 'highslide/highslide.js')}}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{=URL('static', 'highslide/highslide.css')}}" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    hs.graphicsDir = '{{=URL('static', 'highslide/graphics') + '/'}}';
</script>
```